# Way to put pivote sql result into temptable

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

work on sql server .Write one pivotal sql ,bellow is my **tables and pivotal sql syntax**.MY problem is failed to put this pivotal value in Temp table .

```
-----------------Table-1-------------
CREATE TABLE Table1 (ColId INT,ColName VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(1, 'Country')
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(2, 'MONTH')
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES(3, 'Day')



----------------Table-2----------------------------

CREATE TABLE Table2 (tID INT,ColID INT,Txt VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1,1, 'US')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1,2, 'July')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1,3, '4')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (2,1, 'US')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (2,2, 'Sep')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (2,3, '11')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (3,1, 'US')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (3,2, 'Dec')
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (3,3, '25')


--------------
----------------Pivotal sql----------------------------

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                '],[' + t2.ColName
                        FROM    Table1 AS t2
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t2.ColName
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'                    

SET @query = N'SELECT tID, '+
@cols +'
FROM
(SELECT  t2.tID
      , t1.ColName
      , t2.Txt 
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ColId = t2.ColID) p
PIVOT
(
MAX([Txt])
FOR ColName IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY tID;'
EXECUTE(@query)
```

After execute  bellow command want to use this value for rest of work ,so I need to put this command result value in temp table

```
 EXECUTE(@query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to do the rest of your procedure by working with EXECUTE(@Querys) you coud do something like that

```
Declare @TabName Varchar(40)

Select @TabName='##'+Replace(CAST(NEWID() as Varchar(40)),'-','')

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(2000)

SELECT  @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
                                '],[' + t2.ColName
                        FROM    Table1 AS t2
                        ORDER BY '],[' + t2.ColName
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '') + ']'                    

SET @query = N'SELECT tID, '+
@cols +' into ' +@TabName + '
FROM
(SELECT  t2.tID
      , t1.ColName
      , t2.Txt 
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.ColId = t2.ColID) p
PIVOT
(
MAX([Txt])
FOR ColName IN
( '+
@cols +' )
) AS pvt
ORDER BY tID;'

Print @Query
EXECUTE(@query)

Select @query = 'Select * from ' + @Tabname
EXECUTE(@query)

Select @query = 'Drop Table ' + @Tabname
EXECUTE(@query)
```

If you dont want to do that, you could use a "hard" ##temptable, but you would not be able using this save withing a multiuser environment.

Comment: bummi thanks for reply ,but it’s a multiuser environment issue so can not use global ## temp table

Comment: @shamim thats why I created tablename from NEWID, which would enforce you doing the rest of the procedure in the same way. Filling Query and executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Declare @Sample table
(
 tID int,
 Country VARCHAR(10),
 Day int ,
 MONTH  VARCHAR(10)
)

Insert into @Sample 
EXECUTE(@query)

select * from @Sample
```

In the same way you can create a `temp table` instead of `table variable` and insert it into it

Comment: praveen  Thanks for reply,There is one problem I can not create temptable because my  Table1 column increase rapidly so then I need to change this script for temp table you defined , manually .It’s a big problem for me .Help to insert value in temp dynamic table whose column grow dynamically

Comment: If that is the case then i see that you need to change your dynamic query again if the number of column changes